# Error running py2app generated .app, QtWidgets.so "Reason Image not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2app, qtwidgets

I am running into a very frustrating error that occurs when trying to run my python application (.app) generated by py2app – on my 10.12.6 OS X laptop. PyQt5 was installed using pip3, and has been re-installed since the problem. This is the full error code:

```
Last login: Mon Oct 23 00:14:00 on ttys001
/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main ; exit;
Zacharys-MacBook-Pro:~ development$/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main ; exit;

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 386, in <module>
_run()
File "/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 370, in _run
exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
File "/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/main.py", line 4, in <module>
from sheet import Sheet

File "sheet.pyc", line 8, in <module>
File "PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyc", line 14, in <module>
File "PyQt5/QtWidgets.pyc", line 10, in __load
File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError:      dlopen(/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so, 2):      

Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
Referenced from:   /Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/BasicEmail/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so
Reason: image not found
2017-10-23 00:19:19.853 main[31651:3648399] main Error`
```

My code for the sheet.py. The first view of my application:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import io
import csv
#from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Sheet(QWidget):

buttonClicked = pyqtSignal()
email_list = []
#company_list = []

def __init__(self,r,c):
    super().__init__() 
    self.init_ui(r,c)

def init_ui(self,r,c):
    self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()

    self.sheet = QTableWidget()
    self.sheet.setRowCount(r)
    self.sheet.setColumnCount(c) 
    item = QTableWidgetItem('Upload a CSV file with emails.')
    self.sheet.setItem(0, 0, item)

    self.sheet.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.sheet.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(50)

    width = 200        
    self.open_button = TemplateButton(QPixmap('res/open-folder.png'))
    self.open_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    self.continue_button = TemplateButton(QPixmap('res/forward-arrow.png'))
    self.continue_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)        

    self.file_path = None

    self.open_button.clicked.connect(lambda:     self.open_click(self.open_button,"Open",self.sheet))    
    self.continue_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.continue_click(self.continue_button,"Continue"))    

    self.v_layout.addWidget(self.sheet)               
    self.h_layout.addWidget(self.open_button)
    self.h_layout.addWidget(self.continue_button)

    self.v_layout.addLayout(self.h_layout)

    self.setLayout(self.v_layout)
    self.setWindowTitle("EMAIL")        

    self.show()
```

Main I suspect the same other to be called on my others:

```
import sys
import os
import io
from sheet import Sheet
from email_list import EmailList
from construct import ConstructEmail
from construct import NewTemplateDialog, ConfirmDialog
from template_list import TemplateList, TemplateEdit
from settings import Settings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to the problem. While bundling your application you have to include the flag --packages=PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
python setup.py py2app --packages=PyQt5
```